# iOS: UIToolbar or UIView for keyboard in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitoolbar, swift-extensions

I am creating a `UIView` or a `UIToolbar` for my keyboard when I select a textfield.
For example something like that in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
let customView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 40))
        customView.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.2)
        emailTextField.inputAccessoryView = customView
```

and ok it works fine.
But to optimise this cose, which is the best solution? 
For example, put this code in an extension?
Or in a separated Xib?
To have a clean code and not fill my viewController with these stuff.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want all the `UITextField` have this :

```
let v = CustomView()
let textField = UITextField.appearance()
textField.inputAccessoryView = v
```

or make an `extension` then call it when you want :

```
extension UITextField{
    func addInputAccessoryView(){
        let v = CustomView()
        self.inputAccessoryView = v
    }
}
```

Comment: You could write it like this `UITextField.appearance().inputAccessoryView = CustomView()`